# How to set Primary light colors to Button in MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design, emotion

I am new to material UI and react js, I just tried to add 2 buttons, one is with primary color, and another with Primary-light. How can I do that

I am using emotion library. This is what I tried it. I am not trying to change of the default color of primary-light, I wants to use the default primary-light color to my button

```
<Button variant="contained" >Primary Button</Button>
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" >secondary Button</Button>
```

the above 2 buttons are working as expected.

```
<Button variant="contained" color="primary-light" >secondary Button</Button> //I know the syntax is wrong.
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
  <Button
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#f8ad33" }}
        variant="contained"
        // color="primary"
        onClick={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
      >
        Register
      </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

"primary-light" is not one of the supported colours by MUI buttons.
Which you can see in the documentation here [here](https://mui.com/api/button/)

You have a few options:

- Manually override the style of this button. (not ideal).
- Make a class that specifies the colour you want and provide the hex colour code as the background colour. (also not ideal).
- Make a JSX class using makeStyles that takes the app's theme as an argument and provide the `primary.light` colour directly from your theme. (I'm not sure if this is outdated in version 5 of material UI but it is how you would usually do it in v4).

In your case it's probably easiest to take a quick look at the documentation [Here](https://mui.com/components/buttons/#CustomizedButtons.js) Which shows how to customize colours on buttons using your theme and the `styled` function which is imported from mui/material/styles.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create "primaryLight" color property in theme object so I could use. Also had to add types in order to Button can accept "primaryLight".

I used this [document](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/)

Answer (score 0):

A hacky workaround would be to use the defined theme color and then overwrite with sx prop.

```
  <Button
    color={'primary'}
    variant='contained'
    onClick={() => toggle(true)}
    sx={{width: '100%', bgcolor: 'primary.dark', '&:hover': {bgcolor: 'primary.light'}}}
  >
    comments
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is prevented by design.

[Button](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/button/) components are meant to get a [color](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors), and use the color [main](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/palette/#adding-new-colors) key.

You may use `ButtonPropsColorOverrides` to allow more color values, which is useful when you add more colors to the theme, but still - you'll get the color's main key, and cannot access other color keys.

I believe this design is meant to keep the color system integrity. You're not supposed to use `primary.light` key since it may be used for other effects (like hover).

Note that you can use inner color keys for some other components, like typography:

```
<Typography variant="body2" color="primary.light">Hello</Typography>
```